# Loop through a <select> tag and append the content to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, append, nested

I have a `<select>` tag on my site that contains multipe choises options. What i need to do is append all these options in this `<select>` tag into an existing JSON object.

My HTML code:

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="groupSelector">Group:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="groupSelector">
            <option value="guests">guests</option>
            <option value="members">members</option>
            <option value="vips">vips</option>
            <option value="mods">mods</option>
            <option value="admins">admins</option>
            <option value="owners">owners</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Prefix..." class="form-control" id="groupPrefix" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select multiple class="form-control" style="min-height: 170px;" id="groupPermissions">
            <option>permission.node.1</option>
            <option>permission.node.2</option>
            <option>permission.node.3</option>
            <option>permission.node.4</option>
            <option>permission.node.5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="text-right">
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <button value="Save" class="btn btn-default" onclick="save_field_data('perm_manager');">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

You can see in this HTML a `<select>` field with the id of *"groupPermissions"*'

Here is what i need to do: I have this JSON object that i want to append the `<option>` values for the `<select>` field nested inside my JSON object. This is what i want my JSON object to look like:

```js
{
    "selected_group":"mods",
    "prefix":"[Moderator]",
    "permissions": {
        "node": "permission.node.1",
        "node": "permission.node.2",
        "node": "permission.node.3",
        "node": "permission.node.4",
        "node": "permission.node.5",
    }
}
```

Im looking for a way to append all the child elements (The `<option>` tags) for the `<select>` field, and append them to a JSON object and have it as shown above.

This is my current JavaScript that saves the field values. And i need to append the options in here before sending it off for storage on my server.

```js
var permNodes = {};

$('#groupPermissions option').each(function(){
    permNodes.push( {"node": this.value} );
});

var perm_manager_data = {
    selected_group: $("#groupSelector").val(),
    prefix: $("#groupPrefix").val(),
    permissions: permNodes
};

$.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        dataType : 'json',
        async: false,
        url: 'data/save_data.php?file=permissions_manager',
        data: { data: JSON.stringify(perm_manager_data) },
        success: function() {alert("Field data saved successfully!"); },
        failure: function() {alert("An error occured trying to save the field data!");}
    });
```

Comment: What output are you getting now?  Only thing I can see that may need to change is to put a if($(this).is(':selected')){} around permNodes.push( {"node": this.value} );

Comment: @glambert This is what i get out currently: `{"selected_group":"mods","prefix":"[Moderator]","permissions":["permission.node.1", "permission.node.2", "permission.node.3", "permission.node.4", "permission.node.5"]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 thing first**
You cannot have multiple Keys in an object notation with the same name. You at least needs to change your names to something like: node1, node2 etc. And you are actually trying to push elements into an object.

**2 thing**
You can add the options to the javascript object as nodes instead of an array. Like this.

```
permNodes["node"+i] = this.value;
```

**Update 1**
If you really want the permissions to be and array in your json output, then the only change you have to make is:

```
var permNodes = [];
```

Instead of

```
var permNodes = {};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really cant stress enough how helpful this is even though i realize it is a stupid question. People vote down peoples question if it is stupid. But rather than flaming people for it: Try and help them instead. Thank you so much for being one of those that just helps out instead!